# Creating a controller method that saves an object within an object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, microservices

I am trying to create a controller for a microservice in which a vehicle object is created, however within this vehicle object, we must save a registration object first. I am able to do the vehicle controller, but am unsure how to have the registration object saved within the vehicle object. Here is what the JSON objects should look like in the end.

JSON input:

```
{
    "make":"Chevrolet", 
    "Model":"Silverado 1500", 
    "modelYear":2009, 
    "registration": {
        "licensePlate":"TOWME2", 
        "licensedTo":"Ford Towers"
    }
}
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "id":[auto-generated], 
    "make":"Chevrolet", 
    "model":"Silverado 1500", 
    "modelYear":2009, 
    "registration": {
        "id":[auto-generated], 
        "licensePlate":"TOWME2", 
        "licensedTo":"Ford Towers"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and it's because `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` excludes ID fields.

To customize how it behaves, you can extend `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` to expose IDs for specific classes.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Vehicle.class);
    }
}
```